# Difference between "is not reachable" and "unknown host"

Tags: java, url, ping

I've a small java code which test a bunch of hosts which is not reachable.
The important part is this:

```
for (String host : hosts) {
    try {
        if (!InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(5000)) {
            System.err.println(host + " is not reachable!");
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println(host + " is unknown");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(host + "throws IOException!");
    }
}
```

`hosts` is a `String[]`-Array full of URL's to test. When I run it, some URL's comes "*... is not reachable!*" and sometimes it comes "*... is unknown*".

But what is the difference between these two?
**Not reachable** -> No answer after 5sec to the ping
**Unknown** -> No host found to ping

These are only my thoughts and I can't find any confirmations or improvements in google.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Unknown host** means that it couldn't resolve a DNS entry, so it doesn't know what IP address to contact.

**Not reachable** means that it had an IP and tried to contact it but failed (either because of a timeout or because it received a [destination unreachable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Destination_unreachable) message).

Comment: So for example: `Unknow host` is when i ping `www.aöfhdfsadkjfen.com` and `not reachable` when i ping a site which exists but is currently down?

Comment: @dTDesign Correct. Until some spammer notices that domain and registers it.

Answer (score 3):

**Unknown host** - Not enough information is available to contact a host / it does't know which host to contact
**Unreachable** - Enough information is available to contact the host but contact is not happening due to some reason (network error, timeout-host didn't respond on time, privilege issue etc.)